# How can I make Xdebug to connect to 9003 with first VSCode instance and to 9004 to second VSCode instance?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I have same workspace opened in two instances of VSCode. I am debugging PHP.

One is listening on 9003 and one is listening on 9004.

I can change port to other than 9003. For example like below:

```
xdebug.client_port=9004
```

But I want Xdebug to connect to 9003 with first VSCode instance and 9004 to second VSCode instance.

Can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: No.

It is not possible to have Xdebug change the port to which it connects on a per-request bases.

However, there are workarounds.

The first is to use the [DBGp Proxy](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpProxy), where you can have two [recent](https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/pull/685) VSCode instances with a *different* IDE Key register themselves with the proxy, and then on the PHP/web browser site you can use one of the Xdebug [helper browser extensions](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#browser-extensions) to set their IDE Keys to the same value as where you want the debugging request to go to.

The second option is to use [Xdebug Cloud](https://xdebug.cloud) and use a different Cloud ID through the browser extensions. Unfortunately the VS Code plugin does not support this yet, although PhpStorm does.

Comment: You should add `disclaimer: Xdebug Author here` : )

Comment: Agree on the disclosure: I want to know that you know what you're talking about, and disclosure would establish that credibility rather quickly.  Of course, it would also avoid looking shady, which is a nice bonus.